# How do I shoot pictures with the size of above 4MB?

Tags: sony

I am using Sony A6000 and the size of most of the photos is below 1 MB. I want it to be above 4 MB so I can upload on shutterstock.

Comment: Hi akho and welcome to Photo.SE! You question seems to suggest that you don't want to have pictures that have more megabytes, you want to upload photos to shutterstock, which has certain guidelines. Perhaps you can reword your question to describe what you actual goal is? I am sure it is not pictures that have a higher filesize.

Comment: Slightly related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/121395/9161

Comment: Please explain how do you edit your images. My images from the same camera are 12-20MB. Did you set your camera to maximum size of images (L)? https://helpguide.sony.net/gbmig/45349331/v1/en/contents/TP0000522845.html

Comment: okay i just set image size to L24M and aspect ratio 3:2. Image is coming to 6 mb now. how do you get 12-20 mb?

Comment: @akho, please read the related question I posted. File size is not a predictor of image quality. Pursuing higher numbers of mb will not help you get better photo's. Please edit your question to explain what you wan to achieve in the end.

Comment: @akho, I shoot RAW and then edit them. And when export I set very low level of compression.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke its all clear now. but i have another query, why is image of different megabytes though in the same settings

Comment: @akho, please [search the previous question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=mb+settings) to get an answer, e.g. this one: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/116372/9161

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments seems like you set your camera to take small images (in JPEG format). To get bigger images follow [this page](https://helpguide.sony.net/gbmig/45349331/v1/en/contents/TP0000522845.html) and set your camera to L size.

Also Sony use a bit aggressive compression for JPEGs so you can set your camera to shoot RAW and then edit your images and export them with low compression. This will help you to keep more colours.